# Spring Rest API throwing 404 when deployed in QA server

Tags: xml, spring, tomcat, rest

Spring application which exposed the rest API and deployed into the tomcat. The application runs fine in the local but when i deploy into the QA server , the rest api is throwing 404.

the servelt i'm trying is rest/* which i have mapped in the url below.

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>${project.name} (${project.version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}.${SVN_REVISION})</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:META-INF/spring/database-context.xml
            classpath*:META-INF/spring/core-service-context.xml
            classpath*:META-INF/spring/security-service-context.xml
            classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.kukri</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my rest-servelt.xml as below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
        
            <context:component-scan
                    base-package="com.companyname.erp.controller" />
            <mvc:annotation-driven />
        
            <bean id="viewResolver"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
                <property name="defaultViews">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        
        </beans>
```

And deploying the application in the tomcat 9 version and on port 8081. I have checked the work folder under the tomcat which has the application which I'm trying to access and verified the class and that has the controller  when trying to access the URL in postman, curl,wget like below

`http://www.qaerpinterface.companyname.com:8081` it returns `200 OK`

But when I try to call GET on my REST API
`http://www.qaerpinterface.companyname.com:8081/rest/`

it returns me `404`

Below is my server.xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    
    <Server port="${catalina.port.shutdown}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
    
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
    
    
        <GlobalNamingResources>
    
            <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
        </GlobalNamingResources>
    
        <Service name="Catalina">
            <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
                      maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    
            <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                       port="${catalina.port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       connectionTimeout="20000"
                       redirectPort="${catalina.port.https}"
                       compression="on"
                       compressionMinSize="16384"
                       noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla,traviata"
                       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image/svg+xml"/>
            <Connector port="${catalina.port.ajp13}"
                       protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol"
                       executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                       acceptCount="1000"
                       acceptThreadCount="4"
                       processorCache="300"
                       redirectPort="${catalina.port.https}" />
            <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                       prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    
            </Host>
            <Host name="www.qakitdesigner.companyname.com" appBase="webapps/k2-web/webapp"
                  unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false"
                  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                <Context docBase="/opt/tomcat/tomcat8_erp/webapps/k2-web/webapp/ROOT" path="/teamshop" reloadable="true" />
    
            </Host>
            <Host name="www.qaerpinterface.companyname.com" appBase="webapps/k2-erpInterface/webapp"
                  unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false"
                  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                <Alias>www.testerpinterface3.companyname.com</Alias>
                <Context docBase="/opt/tomcat/tomcat8_erp/webapps/k2-erpInterface/webapp/ROOT" path="/erpinterface" reloadable="true" />
            </Host>
        </Service>
    </Server>
```

deployed the two applications two war in the same tomcat do you all think that is causing the issue? but they both have the  different hostname

Any help will be helpful tried all the possible things which are in google changing the controller name, updating the XSD versions.
The server we are running is apache tomcat webservers on Linux machines.

Please help any suggestion on how to debug further or what to change or where to look into?

Comment: The context path in server.xml is path="/erpinterface". Did you try using - qaerpinterface.companyname.com:8081/erpinterface/rest/<view name> ?

Comment: tried that but nothing the context is not working somehow don't know what missing